# Возможность програмирования на планшете

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Ничего не понимаю в программировании, но хочу начать обучатся. Подскажите, возможно ли программирование на планшете?
К компьютеру пока не имею доступа.

Comment: как рассказывают люди постарше, раньше студенты писали программы на бумажках, а потом ждали по месяцу своей очереди, чтобы скормить свое творчество единственной в институте ЭВМ. К чему я это? К тому, что их опыт свидетельствует о том, что программировать на планшете возможно

Comment: Вы не указали на каком языке программирования вы хотите обучаться программированию

Answer (score 5):

Для разработки Android-программ на языке программирования Java есть IDE для android-устройств - [AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com). Возможности ее довольно скромны, по сравнению с десктопными средствами разработки и для начального обучения это тоже не самый лучший вариант, но под платформу Android - лучшее из того, что есть. Ссылка на [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)

C другими языками программирования на платформе Android все несколько печально. Есть инструменты для работы с [С\С++](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ide%20C%2FC%2B%2B&c=apps), но начинать учиться программированию на этих языках крайне не рекомендуется.

Так же есть некие инструменты - [DeuterIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.didactic.DeuterIDE), список поддерживаемых языков впечатляет (40 штук) и [Run The Code](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhangns.runthecode) (20 языков), но что это такое и насколько пригодно для использования сказать не могу, не пользовался.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь именно об **обучении программированию**, а не о серьёзной разработке на планшете, можно посмотреть на [TouchDevelop](https://www.touchdevelop.com/) от Microsoft. Он реализован прямо в браузере, интерфейс изначально проектировался для мобильных платформ. Внутри использует JavaScript, но вам об этом знать пока необязательно (ой, уже поздно).

Возможности у него, конечно, скромные. И полученные знания очень слабо привязываются к конкретному языку, поэтому этого вам хватит до ухода с уровня "абсолютный начинающий".

---

Далее вы, вероятно, захотите работать с реальными языками, и тут уже будут проблемы, поскольку они приспособлены для работы с полноценной клавиатурой, на которой удобно набирать произвольный текст, богатый на пунктуацию. На планшетах пунктуация обычно запрятана в отдельный раздел клавиатуры. Каждый раз на него переключаться это боль. В какой-то мере помогает "хакерская клавиатура" (Hacker's keyboard, [см. Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=ru)), делая клавиатуру чуть более похожей на обычную (более полная раскладка)...

Так уж сконструированы используемые нынче (нормальные, не эзотерические) языки. Всем нужна пунктуация. Даже Ruby, в котором из известных мне языков её меньше всего, без пунктуации далеко не уехать.

Возможным спасением мог бы стать редактор, умеющий расставлять пунктуацию (большую её часть хотя бы) самостоятельно, примерно как это делает [Parinfer](https://shaunlebron.github.io/parinfer/) на основе отступов строк (количества пробелов в начале каждой строки), но это уже далеко не для начинающих, да и ни одна реализация, адаптированная под тачскрины мне пока неизвестна. Впрочем, в связи с успешным переносом ClojureScript в браузер, могут возникнуть!

---

Короче, проблема не в том, что это неудобно. А в том, что инструментов никто не делает, чтобы это **стало** удобным.

Для современных сред разработки считается уже почти требованием выполнение крупных преобразований над кодом. Если реализовать и более мелкие и хорошенько разложить по интерфейсу... теоретически, это может быть удобно. Но этим мало кто занимается.

Answer (score 0):

Купите планшет на Windows установите IntelliJ IDEA + JDK и будет вам счастье. У меня так супруга долгое время изучала Java.